# Face detection web camera showing blank screen open cv

Tags: c#, opencv

I am using a Logitech C920 web camera I am trying my hand at face detection however When I attempt to access my camera with the following code I just get a blank screen. The camera is recognised fine by windows and works in other software.

What I want to do is show the live stream of the web camera in the picture box is this possible

Maybe open cv is not the type of software for this ?

```
private void CaptureCamera()
{
    camera = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureCameraCallback));
    camera.Start();
}

private void CaptureCameraCallback()
{
        frame = new Mat();
        capture = new VideoCapture();
        capture.Open(2);
        while (isCameraRunning == 1)
        {
            capture.Read(frame);
            image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
            image = null;
        }

}
public frmFaceDetection()
{
        InitializeComponent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
capture.Open(2)
```

change it to

```
capture.Open(0)
```

0 correspondes to first camera so this should work.